# Apache Marmotta Importer from Docker

Tags: docker, rdf, triplestore, apache-marmotta

I installed Apache Marmotta with Docker using [docker pull apache/marmotta](http://marmotta.apache.org/installation.html#installation) on an AWS server. I am able to see Core Services (http://34.229.180.217:8080/marmotta/core/admin/import) via the Import interface in my browser. However, I am not able to import RDF files through the interface.

[image: Apache Marmotta]

The files (RDF and TTL) are on both my local machine and on the server. The files are very large (over 2 GB each) and so I'd like to use [KiWi Loader](http://marmotta.apache.org/platform/loaders.html#KiWi_Loader) to bring them into Marmotta so I can run SPARQL queries against them.

Is there a parameter I can adjust in Marmotta to allow for larger file imports? Otherwise, is it possible to use the KiWi Loader through the Docker installation? Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import using the local directory. Just copy your `RDF/TTL` files to `$MARMOTTA_HOME/import`. You can define you context base in file-like structure. For example, if you want to store your data in `http://34.229.180.217:8080/marmotta/foo`, just store your file in `$MARMOTTA_HOME/import/foo`, here you are using the default context. However, if you want to store in other context create a folder with a URL encoded. For more details of the options that Apache Marmotta provide to import files check the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/marmotta/ImportData).

IMHO, I have had a lot of problems uploading big files. I think is mostly because Apache Marmotta commit the data after is everything in memory, it is an implementation of KiWi. I don't if you can upload by chunks, and using `importer.batchsize` property hasn't work much for me.